# VBA for copy paste from file and sheet name as given in excel cell

Tags: vba

I am using following VBA Code to copy data from a closed excel sheet. the name of sheet changes as per the date. so I assign the path and file name from the excel cell `B1`. Now I am stuck at one place only. I want to assign the work sheet name given in another cell `B2`.

```
Sub GetDataClosedBook()

Dim scr As Workbook
Dim FromPath1 As String


'location of the file and data to copy'

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FromPath1 = Sheets("Status").Range("B1")

Set scr = Workbooks.Open(FromPath1)

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Worksheets("Today_BC").Range("B1:P40000").Formula = scr.Worksheets("12SEP2018").Range("A1:O40000").Formula
Workbooks(2).Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Save 

End Sub
```

Now the `("12Sep2018")` keeps changing, I am manually doing right now but I want to assign from cell in worksheet. How can I do it?

Comment: Replace `scr.Worksheets("12SEP2018")...` with `scr.Worksheets(Sheets("Status").Range("B2").Value)...`

Comment: It stopped at Set scr = Workbooks.Open(FromPath1) only... used as -----** Worksheets("Today_BC").Range("B1:P40000").Formula = scr.Worksheets(Sheets("Status").Range("B2").Value).Range("A1:O40000").Formula**

Comment: Thnx Akina, Its working now , it was error from my side on reference cell.. thans a lot on prompt reply also. I had tried the same but not knowing to put ".value " as i am not good at VBA.

Comment: @Akina if you post your solution as an answer then op would be able to accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

> I want to assign the work sheet name given in another cell B2

If so you must replace the string literal of the worksheet name `"12SEP2018"` with the value of a cell where the worksheet name you need is stored. i.e.

```vb
Worksheets("Today_BC").Range("B1:P40000").Formula = _
     scr.Worksheets("12SEP2018").Range("A1:O40000").Formula
```

must be replaced with

```vb
Worksheets("Today_BC").Range("B1:P40000").Formula = _
     scr.Worksheets(Sheets("Status").Range("B2").Value).Range("A1:O40000").Formula
```

Or store the destination worksheet name in a variable:

```vb
StoreTo = Sheets("Status").Range("B2").Value
Worksheets("Today_BC").Range("B1:P40000").Formula = _
     scr.Worksheets(StoreTo).Range("A1:O40000").Formula
```